# What should Muslim do when they forgot to offer shalat?

Tags: salat, muslim-practices

I went to Mountain for vacation and forget to offer shalat when i was home.
Because I realy tired I went to bed earlier and forgot to offer magrib and Isya.

and then the day after I remembered that I didn't Offer Shalat magrib and Isya

What Should I do? answer based on shahih hadist would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You according to hadith should offer the qaza salah (obligatory salah performed not on said time). You should offer the fard part of these salah as soon as you remember that you forgot to perform the obligatory salah.

Reference;

> Ibn Abbas narrated that the Prophet (PBUH) said, “Jibril (AS) led me
>   in (in Salat) twice at the House (the Kaaba). So he prayed Zuhr the
>   first time when the shadow was similar to (the length of) the strap of
>   a sandal. Then he prayed Asr when everything was similar (to the
>   length of) its shadow. Then he prayed Maghrib when the sun had set and
>   the fasting person breaks fast. Then he prayed Isha when the twilight
>   had vanished. Then he prayed Fajr when fajr (the dawn) began, and when
>   eating is prohibited for the fasting person. The second time he prayed
>   Zuhr when the shadow of everything was similar to (the length of) it,
>   at the time of Asr the day before. Then he prayed Asr when the shadow
>   of everything was about twice as long as it. Then he prayed Maghrib at
>   the same time as he did the first time. Then he prayed Isha, the later
>   one, when a third of the night had gone. Then he prayed Subh (Fajr)
>   when the land glowed. Then Jibril (AS) turned towards me and said: O
>   Muhammad (PBUH)! These are the times of the Prophets before you, and
>   the time is what is between these two times.” (Hadith No. 1393, Book
>   of Salat, Sunan Abu Dawud, Vol. 1; Hadith No. 149, Chapters on Salat,
>   Jami’ At-Tirmidhi, Vol. 1).

**Update; In response to your comment (what is qaza salah)**

*In certain circumstances one may be unable to perform one's prayer within the prescribed time period (waqt). In this case, the prayer must be performed as soon as one is able to do so or as soon as one remembers it. Several Ahadith narrate that Muhammad sallallahu alaihi wasalam stated that permissible reasons to perform Qada Salat are forgetfulness and accidentally sleeping through the prescribed time. However, knowingly sleeping through the prescribed time for Salat is deemed impermissible. but still you have to perform the qaza salah.*

**Update - In response to your other coment regarding nonpermissible times for Salah.**

In this condition sun is above horizon and **you can offer Salah**
[image: In this condition sun is above horizon and **you can offer Salah**]

In this condition sun is still half below horizon, and **you cannot offer Salah**
[image: In this condition sun is still half below horizon, and **you cannot offer Salah**]

Any more clarifications regarding this question required leave a comment.
Regarding any other topic it would be better to ask another question

Comment: i'm new to Islam I didn't know about qaza? please explain it more detail thanks

Comment: Insha Allah, brother/Sister I will explain the qaza salah to you as simply as I can. But wait a while while I collect the sources

Comment: kinda confused to read the hadist.Correct me if i'm wrong, so I have to offer shalat at the time when I remember, it means anytime when I remember i offer the shalat regardless the time of the shalat?

Comment: yes, any-time as soon as you remember. except at two times; during sun rise until the disk of sun is completely above visible horizon and during sun set until the disk of sun is completely below the visible horizon

Comment: if you have any other query comment back here

Comment: if you understood what you wanted, then please confirm it

Comment: the disk of the sun is completely above horizon? you mean at 12 pm? stil don't get it? maybe you should convert it to times so I can Undrstand completely.

Comment: It means when the sun is red in early morning. I'll add some images to my answer to help out

Comment: Sorry brother, for now I cannot repond immidiately to you!. Insha Allah will respond tommorow.

Answer (score 0):

It was narrated that Abu Qatadah said: "They told the Prophet (ﷺ) that they had slept and missed the prayer. He said: 'There is no negligence when one sleeps, rather negligence is when one is awake. If any one of you forgets a prayer or sleeps and misses it, let him pray it when he remembers it.'"